# Vectorizing an indexing operation in numpy

Tags: python, indexing, numpy

What is the best way to vectorize the following code in numpy?

```
from numpy import *

A = zeros(5, dtype='int')
I = [1, 1, 1, 3]
J = [2, 1, 1, 1]
for i, j in zip(I, J):
    A[i] += j

print A
```

The result should be:

```
[0 4 0 1 0]
```

Here `A` is the original array, `I` stores the index at which we want to increment by the corresponding entry of `J`.

If one simply vectorizes the above by doing:

```
A[I] += J
print A
```

one gets the wrong answer

```
[0 1 0 1 0]
```

as, apparently, repeated indices are ignored. Is there an equivalent operation to `+=` which does not ignore repeated indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.bincount()`:

```
A = numpy.zeros(5, dtype='int')
I = [1, 1, 1, 3]
J = [2, 1, 1, 1]
sums = numpy.bincount(I, J)
A[:len(sums)] += sums
print(A)
```

prints

```
[0 4 0 1 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

In principle you can do it with `numpy`'s `bincount` and `unique`, but I'd guess it'll only make the code much less readable without any sensible performance improvement.